# Add a Class with byte[] to NSUserDefaults in iOS Share Extension (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults, share-extension

In **Xamarin.iOS Share Extension**, I'd like to store my selected files (like pdf, images, word etc.) in my **NSUserDefaults** and when the main application starts, I'll have access to the files stored in it.

Here is my file class :

```
public class MyClass {    
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; } 
}
```

So in **LoadItem** in **DidSelectPost** methods, I create by object by using **byte[]** of files. Then for saving datas in **NSUserDefaults**, I convert my object to **JSON** like this (by using **Newtonsoft.Json library**):

```
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFileObject);
```

and I set it to **NSUserDefaults** object like that:

```
NSUser.SetValueForKey(new NSString(myFileObject), new NSString("FileSharing" + count));
```

or

```
NSUser.SetValueForKey(new NSString(myFileObject), new NSString("FileSharing"+ count));
```

And after I'll synchronise my items : `NSUser.Synchronize());`

Everything goes well, but when the **main application** open, the new data is not here.

```
string toDesralize = nSUser.StringForKey("FileSharing0");
```

I've tried for many files, and I've found out that this issue works only for files with low height and it doesn't work for files like 14mb. How can i save files with high height in **NSUserDefaults**? Is there any other way for doing the same job ?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is for small bits of data - not storing entire files.  What you're trying to do is a bad idea.  If you need to store large files, just use the file system.

Comment: that's correct, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [file system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system#general-file-access) to store and read data in Xamarin.iOS:

```
    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    var filename = Path.Combine(documents, "Write.txt");
    //save text
    File.WriteAllText(filename, "Write this text into a file");
    //save bytes
    File.WriteAllBytes(filename,yourBytes);
```

And the read methods:

```
    var text = File.ReadAllText("TestData/ReadMe.txt");
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Your are correct, I've to use file system

Comment: following your answer, I've tried to create a text file which is accessible in both applications : main application & share extension. this file must be placed app group container (otherwise no access in both). I've tried to select files with 15mb for example => No success ! I think it's too heavy for share extension but I don't know why ? do you have any idea? it crashed without any error

Comment: If the file is large, I think you need to use SQLite.NET. Here are documents: [Using SQLite.NET with Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/data/using-sqlite-orm) and [Introduction to Data Storage in Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/data/introduction).

Comment: Okay ! Thanks one more time